# Operator Overloading in C

Tags: c++, c, operators, operator-overloading

In C++, I can change the operator on a specific class by doing something like this:

```
MyClass::operator==/*Or some other operator such as =, >, etc.*/(Const MyClass rhs) {
    /* Do Stuff*/;
}
```

But with there being no classes (built in by default) in C.  So, how could I do operator overloading for just general functions?

For example, if I remember correctly, importing stdlib.h gives you the -> operator, which is just syntactic sugar for (*strcut_name).struct_element.

So how can I do this in C?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're implying by saying "no classes (built in by default)", but there are no classes in C, period.  Built-in or otherwise.  And what do you mean operator overloading for functions?  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well, you can create an object-model in C with classes, but it will not by using syntax other than plain C syntax. For my attempts at this, see http://jonsterling.github.com/2009/08/28/implementing-object-oriented-programming-in-pure-c.html and http://jonsterling.github.com/2009/09/07/object-oriented-programming-in-c-mark-two.html.

Comment: Jonathan had the proper intuition as to what I was suffering to.  I was saying that you could force C into an OOP model.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Plain old C does not have operator overloading in any form.  The `->` "operator" to access a member of a pointer is standard C and is not introduced by any header file.

Comment: Indeed. `->` is just special syntax because pointers to structs are so common.

Comment: I see.  So, basically, the only type of operator overloading would be some sort of preprocessor directive, say:
#define plus(a,b) a+b.  Although, that wouldn't allow for any form of parameters, unless you can somehow get it to change a and b to the actual parameter names...

Comment: @Leif: I don't think a macro is appropriate for what you're saying.  If you want `struct foo` to have some notion of addition, then you would typically define a function `foo add_foos(foo lhs, foo rhs)` or something to that extent.  There's no need to get the preprocessor involved in this.  If you switch to C++ later, then you can overload `+` to call `add_foos`.

Answer (score 5):

Built-in operators in C language are *overloaded*. The fact that you can use binary `+` to sum integers, floating-point numbers and perform pointer arithmetic is a canonical example of *operator overloading*.

However, C offers no features for user-level operator overloading. You can't define your own operators in C.

Answer (score 1):

The `->` structure pointer dereferencing operator is part of the C spec.  `stdlib.h` does not affect this.

Comment: Rats, okay, thank you.  I remember a grad student at my university telling me that.

Comment: Don't trust a grad student to know anything about a language unless he's written an implementation of it himself. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can't overload operators in C.
The -> operator is part of the C language, no #include needed.